# Sending a multipart request using RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I want to make a multipart request to some external API (created using Spring Boot) but all I get is `Required request part 'file' is not present`.

I know the source code of the external API but I can't modify it. It looks like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

And from my application I create and send requests exactly like on the following snippet:

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body
                = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("file", "dupa".getBytes());

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity
                = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
                .postForEntity("http://api:8080/upload", requestEntity, String.class);
        return response.getBody();
```

What's the reason it doesn't work? The above code rewritten using Apache HttpClient works like charm.

Comment: As far as I know, the datatype of value for "file" should be `FileSystemResource` in your `MultiValueMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options, the solution with byte array:

```
    map.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(byteArrayContent) {
        @Override
        public String getFilename() {
            return "yourFilename";
        }
    });
```

I remember having a problem with just adding a byte array, so you need to have a filename too and use ByteArrayResource.

Or adding a File:

```
    map.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));
```

Comment: Well, that explains why HttpClient works. It has the filename field in one of its constructors. I wonder why no one explained it properly on the Internet. Thanks